# Approximation by finite sets

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness

I'm reading the book "Topology and Order" by L.Nachbin.

In chapter $3$ he speaks about properties of compact Hausdorff spaces. He writes:

> [A]lthough these spaces may be infinite, they admit approximation by
>   finite sets (in the sense expressed in precise terms by the covering
>   property of Borel-Lebesgue).

What is the exact formulation of this property? I couldn't find anything relevant when I tried searching these terms (approximation by finite sets and covering property) online.

Any formulations and/or references would be of great help!

Thank you.

Comment: Borel-Lebesgue is also known as Heine-Borel, which is far easier to google.

Comment: @mixedmath, sure, but then I get the well known Heine-Borel theorem for subsets of $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: Try "compactness" plus "open covers"...

Comment: @Etienne, then I get the standard definitions of compactness. If the space is compact, then every open cover has a finite subcover, but where do the finite sets come from?

Comment: @Ludolila If for example your space is a metric space, you fix some $\varepsilon >0$ and you cover the space by the family of all open balls of radius $\varepsilon$, your finite covering tells you that there is a finite set such that any point of the space is at distance less than $\varepsilon$ from the finite set. In this sense, the whole space is "approximated" by finite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compact *metric* spaces there is a very precise formulation:

> If $X$ is a compact metric space, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite set $A\subset X$ such that every point of $X$ is within distance less than $\epsilon$ from some point of $A$.

The proof is what Etienne wrote in a comment: take a finite subcover of the open cover $$\{B_\epsilon(x): x\in X\}$$
where $B_\epsilon(x) = \{y\in X: d(y,x)<\epsilon\}$.

For general compact Hausdorff spaces the notion of "approximation" is necessarily vague, since approximation means being "close" to something, and we don't have a metric to quantify the concept of "close". I'd say the following:

> If for every point $x\in X$ we designate some neighborhood of $x$ as "small" (based on whatever criterion), then the whole space can be covered by finitely many "small" neighborhoods.

The proof is essentially the same as in the metric space.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense if we can define "closeness" in some way. But then again, the space is compact and Hausdorff, and thus it has the unique uniformity defined on it. Maybe one can use entourages as a way of measuring "closeness"...